# How to get the evolution equation of reduced density operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, density-operator

Here is a simple system such that we can get the exact evolute equation for reduced density operator, but I'm not sure how to derive it from the result proved in the first part of this question. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/93isy.jpg

EDIT: Someone has closed this question, so I come back to explain the main "concept" part underline the problem(though the question has already been solved). The key question is that "Will the evolution of reduced operator  be influenced by whether the state correspondents to the operator is mixed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, $H = H(1) + H(2)$ means that $\left\lbrace 1 \right\rbrace$ and $\left\lbrace 2 \right\rbrace$ evolve independently. If that is the case, you should be able to treat $\left\lbrace 1 \right\rbrace$ as follows:

$$\frac{d}{dt} \rho(1) = -\frac{i}{\hbar}\left[H(1), \rho(1) \right] \quad \quad \quad \mathbf{(1)}$$

To show this, start by writing $\rho(1) = \mathrm{Tr}_2(\rho)$, and use $\frac{d}{dt} \rho(1) = \frac{d}{dt} \left(\mathrm{Tr}_2(\rho) \right) = \mathrm{Tr}_2 \left(\frac{d}{dt} \rho \right)$.

From this, you have:

$$\frac{d}{dt} \rho(1) = \mathrm{Tr}_2 \left(\frac{d}{dt} \rho \right) = -\frac{i}{\hbar} \mathrm{Tr}_2 \left( \left[H(1) + H(2), \rho \right] \right) = -\frac{i}{\hbar} \mathrm{Tr}_2 \left( \left[H(1), \rho \right] \right) -\frac{i}{\hbar} \mathrm{Tr}_2 \left( \left[H(2), \rho \right] \right)$$

The first term is equal to what you expect (you can pass the trace over $\rho$ because $H(1)$ does not act on $\left\lbrace 2 \right\rbrace$).

The second term can be written as $-\frac{i}{\hbar} \left( \mathrm{Tr}_2 \left( H(2) \rho \right) - \mathrm{Tr}_2 \left( \rho H(2) \right) \right)$. Using the first part of the question, you can try to figure out why it is $0$.

As for physical interpretation, equation $\mathbf{(1)}$ shows that system $\left\lbrace 1 \right\rbrace$ is evolving "on its own", with the Hamiltonian $H(1)$, and is completely decoupled from system $\left\lbrace 2 \right\rbrace$.

Comment: I'm confusing about the part: $−i/ℏ(Tr_2(H(2)ρ)−Tr_2(ρH(2)))−i/ℏ(Tr_2(H(2)ρ)−Tr_2(ρH(2)))=0$                how can we use the first part result directly? Is this to say $Tr_2(ρH(2))=Tr_2(ρ(2)H(2))$? But how can this be true?

Comment: $H(2)$ acts only on $\left\lbrace 2 \right\rbrace$, so that from the first part $\mathrm{Tr}_2(\rho H(2)) = \mathrm{Tr}_2(H(2) \rho)$...

Comment: Aha, I see the problem where I get wrong, I was thinking that both A and B should act on the same one space. Now I'm a little confused about the result we derived, since although the Hamiltonian can be decomposed, it's not necessary be true that the state in this system is decomposable, hence the density operator can not be decomposed generally. But the result in this question says the evolution of each reduced density operator evolute independently. So in a word, the time evolution of density operator is decided only by Hamiltonian but not related to whether the state is decomposable?

Comment: Basically, yes.If the two Hamiltonians are decoupled, you can describe the evolution of the two density matrices of the subsystem independently, and this even if $\rho$ is not decomposable. If for instance $\rho$ correponds to the pure state $1/\sqrt{2}\left(\left|\uparrow_1\downarrow_2\right\rangle+\left|\downarrow_1\uparrow_2\right\rangle\right)$, $\rho(1)$ will not be pure ($\rho(1)=1/2(\left|\uparrow_1\right\rangle\left\langle\uparrow_1\right| +\left|\downarrow_1\right\rangle\left\langle\downarrow_1\right|$),however it will still obey $\frac{d}{dt} \rho (1)=-\frac{i}{\hbar}[H(1),\rho(1)]$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful.